# Apple’s private relay TLS connection

Tags: tls, apple

If I turn on [Apple’s private relay](https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/06/10/how-apple-icloud-private-relay-works) function on my iPad, will the TLS handshake still be with the website I am visiting or with the ingress proxy by Apple?

Or in other words, can Apple or the exgress proxy read my internet traffic with this function enabled?

Comment: I did a google search for " Apple’s private relay" and got tons of hits explaining how it works, including the link I provided in your question. And the top hit walks it through for you: https://www.techradar.com/uk/news/what-is-apple-private-relay-and-is-it-worse-than-a-vpn

Comment: Hey, thanks! I found this kind of information too, but my question is more specific. If I go to a website which uses TLS or https is the TLS handshake than done with this website or with the entry server. Since this entry server makes a TLS connection if I use just http. I have no doubt Apple will not read my communication, but still.

Comment: This PDF from Apple explains the protocol in more detail. No party has the ability to read HTTPS traffic. https://www.apple.com/privacy/docs/iCloud_Private_Relay_Overview_Dec2021.PDF

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. The TLS connection is established with the intended website. On my Mac with the Monterey beta it is possible in Safari to check the TLS certificate which is exactly the same with or without Apple's private relay. So I think it's safe to asume that's the case on an iPad of iPhone as well.